# What's the simplest definition of a MyList.flatten

Tags: list, scala, implicit, flatten

I'm trying to define an custom list, which is like the built-in `List[+A]`, but much simpler:

```
sealed trait MyList[+A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => MyList[B]): MyList[B]
  def map[B](f: A => B): MyList[B]
  def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): MyList[B]
}


case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing] {
  override def flatMap[B](f: (Nothing) => MyList[B]): MyList[B] = ???
  override def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: (Nothing) => GenTraversableOnce[B]): MyList[B] = ???
}

case class MyCons[A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A] {
  override def flatMap[B](f: (A) => MyList[B]): MyList[B] = ???
  override def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: (A) => GenTraversableOnce[B]): MyList[B] = ???
}
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to define the `flatten` method. I copied the implicit value `asTraversable` from somewhere:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): MyList[B]
```

But not sure how to implement it, even not sure if it's correct.

How to make an custom list `flatten`able with simplest defination?

Comment: Think about how would you want Flatten to act, in the case where the type of the list is not something it makes sense to flatten. e.g. what happens if you call `List[Int].flatten`?

Comment: @mattinbits That's the problem I can't handle. Not sure to make it only `flatten`able for `List[T[_]]`, where `T` is traversable

Comment: For a regular scala list, you get a compile time error for `List(1,2,3).flatten` If you're looking for a simpler approach you could make it a runtime exception and check whether the type of your list is Traversable when flatten is called. Then you don't need GenTraversableOnce in the signature

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want it to do. I don't see anything wrong with `List(1,2,3).flatten` returning `List(1,2,3)`, but the standard library makes this a compile error. If you're "simplifying", you're not going to get all the behaviour of the original. The standard library includes the complexity of implicits in order to deal with Arrays, which aren't scala collections, but can be used as such. Is this a complexity you can eliminate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to define a method `fromTraversable` somewhere, perhaps in the companion object:

```
object MyList {
  def fromTraversable[T](t: Traversable[T]): MyList[T] = 
    if (t.isEmpty) MyNil 
    else MyCons(t.head, fromTraversable(t.tail)) 
}
```

This method can generally be useful for your list implementation anyway.

And then `flatten` is simply a call to `flatMap` (you'll need to implement `flatMap`, of course):

```
sealed trait MyList[+A] {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => MyList[B]): MyList[B] = ???
  def flatten[B](implicit ev: A <:< Traversable[B]): MyList[B] = 
    flatMap(MyList.fromTraversable(_))
}
```

Implicit parameter `ev`:

- makes this a compile error to call `flatten` on anything other than a `MyList` of `Traversable`;
- makes available an implicit conversion from `A` to `Traversable[B]`. This conversion gets applied on the argument to `MyList.fromTraversable`.